# d3 mercator, geo, and path methods

Tags: d3.js

I am following this tutorial on d3:

In it, I see this code:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(500)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

And likewise the path generator:

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

What are these methods doing exactly? Is there good documentation on these d3 methods? On on the d3 docs. it says:

"# d3.geo.mercator()

> "The spherical Mercator projection is commonly used by tiled mapping
>   libraries (such as OpenLayers and Leaflet). For an example displaying
>   raster tiles with the Mercator projection, see the d3.geo.tile plugin.
>   It is conformal; however, it introduces severe area distortion at
>   world scale and thus is not recommended for choropleths."

So is d3.geo.mercator just a kind of map design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map projection just converts points from one system (sphere/ellipsoid based latitude/longitudes) into another system (2d Cartesian plane with x/y values).

Mercator is one (very common) way of doing that.  For more about map projections, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection.

With the code you've posted, it sets up a Mercator projection, that when passed a `[long, lat]` point it will return an `[x, y]` point that corresponds to the x and y position that can be drawn on an `svg` or `canvas`.  In this case it will be centered at `[width/2, height/2]`.

The path generator is some d3 "magic" that converts a list of points into an `svg` `path` string.  `svg` has it's own "language" for paths, you can find out more at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html, but that does get pretty technical.

Since `svg` talks in pixel co-ordinates, and most geo data is referenced to lat/long, the projection function allows you to easily convert from one to the other and back again.

Since drawing a path on a map is a very common activity, `d3` includes the path generator that is projection "aware" and will automatically apply the projection specified to whatever data you pass to the path generator, which will result in the pixel co-ordinates getting returned, which will then be converted into the `path` "language" mentioned above, which can then be displayed on an `svg` element.

Comment: Why does d3 by default look in the public folder in rails app?

Comment: Sounds like that's a comment for a different question?